# calculating Product Cost Price in runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am developing an Inventory system, using average cost method, where average cost price of product changes on each new purchase. Database I am using is SQL Server 2008

Now I need to calculate COST OF GOODS SOLD in a report, where I have to Add Cost Price for Each Sale of a product, but this COST PRICE should be relevant to a that specific Purchase period.

My Purchase Table

```
Purchase_Date   Product_ID   Ave_Cost_Price
1-jan-2013      1                  5.5
15-jan-2013     1                  6.5
30-jan-2013     1                  7.5
```

My Sales Table

```
Sale_Date   Product_ID    Sale_Price Cost_Price
5-jan-2013      1              10         ?         SALE-1
17-jan-2013     1              10         ?         SALE-1
31-jan-2013     1              15         ?         SALE-1
```

Now when I create a SALE report, SALE-1 should take 5.5, SALE-2, 6.5 and SALE-3 should pick 7.5 as Product cost price. and if it cannot find any purchase then it should pick opening Cost_Price from product_table.

I am looking for Such a Query which should do the job???

I think may be it can be done by some grouping and inner joins, but cannot figured it out.

any suggestions please ????

regards Raza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of correlated subqueries in the `select` clause.  Part of the reason is aesthetic and mmaintainability.  I prefer to have all table references in one place, in the `from` clause.  Part of the reason is performance; I tend to think that they turn into nested loop joins (usually for worse).  Admittedly, SQL optimizers have gotten much better in the last few years.

But this is one case where I think it is the best approach:

[trouble uploading]

The correlated subquery is . . .

```
select s.*,
```

(select top 1 ave_cost_price
            from purchase p
            where p.purchase_date <= sys.sale_date and p.product_id = s.product_id
            order by p.purchase_date desc
           ) a purchaseprice
    from sales s

And the performance should be fine if you have an index on `purchase(product_id, purchase_date)` or even `purchase(product_id, purchase_date, ave_cost_price)`.

Comment: thanks for reply, Please have a look again on question as I have edited it for one more thing, and can you please explain why you don't like correlated subqueries, is there could be a performance issue, as I will be running this query for about 1500 products having more than 100 sales per day for each product

Comment: @user1115284 . . . I edited the solution, but I'm still having trouble formatting the SQL code.  At least it is all there now.

Comment: Thanks, and I guess, need an other query to get opening cost price from product table, in case no purchases found for a product :)

Comment: @user1115284 . . . Yes, if that is the business rule for handling this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Join both tables on product id and date - month and year portion only, order by id+month/year. Subtract... Sorry, no query as you did not post any data.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to do reporting on this kind of data is to create a data warehousing table that is de-normalized. In it, you would have columns for the sales and additional columns for anything calculated, like cost. Fill in the first columns with an insert based on sales and then fill in the rest of the columns with a second insert query that selects the proper cost. Your reports will then run against this data warehouse table.

The gains in speed and simplicity here are obvious, especially if you have lots and lots of records. You will also have a very easy time writing reports against this "flat" table. The only drawback to this is that any changes to the original data would need to be reapplied to the warehouse table. Typically, though,  you would populate the warehouse table before some "closing" period beyond which the records will no longer be changed. As for how to select the correct cost, most places would use a dollar cost average for goods over a given period instead of trying to match some specific purchase "lot" against a sale. Otherwise, in the method you have described, it becomes virtually impossible to handle things like returns. What cost do you assign to a returned product? I suppose if the items are large enough to have a serial number or other unique identifier then you could do it. But, in that case, your select query for cost would not be date related. It would be ID related.